Why is there a comma here in this sentence?
Came across this sentence:
The album is a heartfelt cry, redolent of a time before radio and television.
Why is there a comma before the “redolent…” clause?
What is the grammar structure of the “redolent…” part?
Thank you

The site guidelines suggest that you should try to research your question before asking us. You have not done this, which may explain why someone voted the question down. However, we also try to encourage new members, so I have tried to answer your question.
